# Google Map GeoCoding API does not work for some postal codes while it works for some other postal code in the same country

Tags: jquery, angularjs, google-maps

I am using the below API to get coordinates using input as postal_code & country (DE in my case which is Germany):

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?components=postal_code:13627|country:DE&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

But the same API gives results for some postal codes while for some others, it does not give results

Not giving results for below postal codes - DE (Germany):

```
13627
21129
14656
85057
74172
30559
```

giving results for below postal codes - DE (Germany):

```
85356
69190
79183
80634
38106
69190
```

Our app is a webportal (Angular JS, JQuery based).

What is the issue?

Comment: I see if we use the country as DEU, it works. Is there something changed in the Google API database as the same code was working for many years for country  as DE.

Comment: It looks like only the one working on your end is the `ISO 3166-1 alpha-3` instead of the `ISO 3166-1 alpha-2` in the `country` component. It would be nice for you to file a bug for a better line of support. https://developers.google.com/maps/support#issue_tracker